# How to use dispatch Redux actions in a separate function scripts in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Lets say i have the below component. The script has become really large and I want to put my doSomething function into another script.

However dispatch can only be used in a React component

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import { toggle_progress_bar } from "../../actions/toggle_progress_bar";
import { set_progress } from "../../actions/set_progress.js";

export default function Example ({}){

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const doSomething = ()=>{

dispatch(set_progress(1))
dispatch(toggle_progress_bar())

}

const handlePress =()=>{

doSomething()
}



return(
<p onClick={handlePress)>just an example </p>
)
}
```

I've tried

Note the value 1 is just an example. The value may come from an axios request etc made in the doSomething function

```
export const doSomething = (toggle_progress_bar, set_progress) =>{

toggle_progress_bar()
set_progress(1)
}
```

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import { toggle_progress_bar } from "../../actions/toggle_progress_bar";
import { set_progress } from "../../actions/set_progress.js";
import {doSomething} from "./doSomething.js"

export default function Example ({}){

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handlePress =()=>{

doSomething(dispatch(toggle_progress_bar()),dispatch(set_progress()))

}



return(
<p onClick={handlePress)>just an example </p>
)
}
```

But I am getting various errors.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const doSomething = (toggle_progress_bar, set_progress) =>{

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return () => {
    dispatch(toggle_progress_bar());
    dispatch(set_progress(1));
  };
}
```

Then call it **doSomething()**

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing dispatch as an argument.